# Prevent Kendo UI datepickers from sharing state

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've noticed a curious issue with the Kendo datepicker.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.BirthDate)
    .Start(CalendarView.Century)
)

@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.FutureDate)
    .Start(CalendarView.Month)    
)
```

Without a default value, both datepickers open focused on the current date. However, if you select a date on one, the other will focus on that same date. For example, if I select Jan 7th, 1970 for BirthDate, FutureDate will then open focused on the month of Jan 1970.

If a default value is provided, each datepicker remains focused on that date.

I'd prefer each datepicker remain focused on the current date, but I don't want to set the current date as default -- I'd prefer each datepicker remain blank until set by the user.

Any solutions? I'm currently on Kendo 2012.3.1315 -- does this happen in the latest version? If not, I might be able to convince my team to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, some time later:

I was able to test the most recent version of Kendo (Q2 2013) and it appears this issue has been fixed. Unfortunately, my team doesn't want to upgrade at the moment. I created this Javascript fix to get around the problem.

```
function fixKendoDatePicker(datepicker) {
    if (!datepicker.value()) {
       datepicker.value(new Date());
       datepicker.dateView._calendar();
       datepicker.value(null);
    }
}
```

The call to _calendar() makes the widget change its internal calendar to match its value -- otherwise, it *usually* wouldn't change unless the datepicker popup was opened, and this method would have no effect.